# Can't create new task with schtasks... Why?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I have a new Windows Server 2008 R2 host with a strange (?) behavior. 
I try to schedule a new task into Task Scheduler.
I'm using a user that's part of administrators group.

1. If I do it from the Task Scheduler GUI - the task is scheduled successfully.
2. If I try to do it from a cmd window - it fails with "access denied"
   (no further info).
3. If I open the cmd window with "Run as
   administrator" -it is scheduled successfully.

I have to make #2 works since I use it in a batch file. Can you tell me what could be the reason and how to resolve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

are administrative shares (c$, admin$ etc) enabled? can you access them using this account? i would reboot the machine, if that's not possible, logout/in.

you can also look at user access control in windows control panel to make sure there's no restriction. please try disabling it. let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just running as a user in the administrators group does not mean that you are using your elevated token.  By running cmd as an admin you are using your elevated token.  To run a batch file as an admin, you can just right click and run it as an admin as well.

Answer (score 0):

UAC prevents you from executing certain admin level commands even if you're logged in with an account that has administrator rights. You can either manually right-click on the batch file and choose "Run as Administrator" or disable UAC (not recommended) to avoid this scenario.